# Moderator abuse of power?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators, deleted-answer, deleted-questions

Nearly all of my answers and questions are either being deleted or put on hold, despite meeting all the criteria/not breaking any rules to my knowledge.

Example: [Does Allah commit shirk by swearing on things lesser than Him (e.g. the Qur'an)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17099/does-allah-commit-shirk)

(Here is a backup since it's about to be deleted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUpO0.png)

In a couple days it became one of the most popular questions on the site. I clearly explained my question, well sourced it, etc. 'pseudoGold', a moderator, put it "on hold" claiming my question was unclear, per his request I further clarified, yet it remains locked.

2nd example: [Nulify the gospels?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7955/nulify-the-gospels)

My answer has been deleted by moderator 'Ansari', link to answer here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aaxim.png .

In the above, I re-iterated the question, then provided a well-sourced answer explaining my interpretation of the passages.

3rd example: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17042/i-am-drawing-a-picture-of-mohammed-what-did-he-look-like (Entire question was deleted, backup here https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQKGI.png ).

My answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeVJx.png . Deleted without explanation, to my knowledge I didn't break any rules. My answer was clearly controversial, but is controversy valid warrant for deletion?

At least two more questions/answers I posted were either locked or deleted.

I don't want to insinuate anything, but from following the moderators above (Ansari and goldPseudo), it's clear they have a positive bias towards Islam. The StackExchange is not only for Muslims, but also scholars/those interested in Islam; content that's not breaking any rules should not be deleted simply because moderators have a different opinion from the poster.

**My question is**, what rules did I break to warrant deletion of my content? If none were broken, Is there an administrator who's attention I can bring this to?

Comment: If you want to know why a particular action was taken on a particular post, please ask those as separate questions with the [meta-tag:specific-question] tag with a clear explanation of *what* exactly you don't understand (especially if there are already existing comments explaining the action).  Otherwise, this is effectively just a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

### Aslam-o-Alaikum

Your [second question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7955/nulify-the-gospels) is okay

> **[Nullify the Gospels](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7955/nulify-the-gospels)**

This question is legit and it isn't deleted. I can see that you have well researched one that question and asked in sense.
The other two questions are out of sense. Don't know why are you asking. Let me clear your mind.

> **[Q : Does Allah commit shirk?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17099/does-allah-commit-shirk)**

In what sense are you asking that "does Allah commint shirk?". This world is created by Allah and good or bad deeds are created for us by Allah. These both deeds will be nothing after judgment day because you won't have to do anything, everything will be perfect.
In question, you said that there are many things that Allah has swear on. Shirk is if someone is associating someone with Allah that he has same powers has Allah or something like this. Swearing isn't associating.
So this question just doesn't match what you have asked.

> **[I am drawing a picture of Mohammed, what did he look like?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17042/i-am-drawing-a-picture-of-mohammed-what-did-he-look-like)**

This question is too straight forward. First, you should ask that "can you draw a picture or not" and than come here to ask if it is possible. So let me tell you, capturing human is forbidden in Islam.

**Narrated Ibn Abbas:

The Prophet (ﷺ) entered the Ka`ba and found in it the pictures of (Prophet) Abraham and Mary. On that he said' "What is the matter with them ( i.e. Quraish)? They have already heard that angels do not enter a house in which there are pictures; yet this is the picture of Abraham. And why is he depicted as practicing divination by arrows?" 

*[Sahih al-Bukhari 3351 - Book 60, Hadith 31](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/31)***
Look, even the pictures of prophets are bad that angles won't come to place where picture are. How can you think to draw a picture of a Prophet?

> **Your Answer**

You should read the background of **[Ubayd-Allah ibn Jahsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubayd-Allah_ibn_Jahsh)** before posing such answer. I didn't know about him but just by reading your answer, the words **fat** and **dwarf**, don't you feel these words as insult?

---

Now come to community guidelines. If you are also on other communities than Islam, you must know how to write a question or an answer. You need to search and than ask or share. 
No one would come in community to ask that "what should I write after alphabate **"A"**?

Comment: Thanks for answering some of the questions I asked, I'm glad it's not too confusing for you to understand and give me an answer. I still am not sure why they were deleted other than for being controversial.

Comment: Its an clear answer, this is other thing that you didn't understand the points.